# C++ Compile Error: array has incomplete element type 'int []'

Tags: c++, methods, multidimensional-array

I am writing a Conway's Game of Life in C++. I get a compile time error having something to do with the way I am passing 2-d arrays to methods:

```
gameoflife.cpp:5:25: error: array has incomplete element type 'int []'
void print_game(int game[][], int SIZE);

gameoflife.cpp:6:23: error: array has incomplete element type 'int []'
void run_game(int game[][], int SIZE);

gameoflife.cpp:7:23: error: array has incomplete element type 'int []'
void set_cell(int game[][], int i, int j, int next[][], int SIZE);
```

etc.

The beginning of my code is:

```
void print_game(int game[][], int SIZE);
void run_game(int game[][], int SIZE);
void set_cell(int game[][], int i, int j, int next[][], int SIZE);
```

Evidently the problem begins here.

What is the issue with passing a 2-d array in a method? Should I use a ** instead?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Um, not really.

Comment: OP, recommended reading: [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: @jrok _'not really'_ Not exactly, yes. But boils down to the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the issue with passing a 2-d array in a method? Should I use a `**` instead?

Not really - if possible, you should use `std::vector` of vectors, like this:

```
#include <vector>
...
void print_game(std::vector<std::vector<int> > game) {
    ... // No need to pass the size
}
```

Passing a built-in 2D array would require you either to specify one of the two dimensions as a constant, or allocate an array as an array of pointers, and then pass a pointer to pointer (i.e. `int **`). Neither of these choices is optimal: the first limits your array to a compile-time maximum, while the second requires you to do a decent amount of manual memory management.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an array of array's without specifying the size first, or passing them as a pointer. the best you could do would be

```
array[][5] //doesn't HAVE to be five, just example value
```

highly recommend taking @dasblinkenlight's route however, using two dimensional arrays should be avoided c++.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int game[][]
```

is a declaration of an array of incomplete type because size of element for example game[0] of the array is unknown. You have to specify sizes of all dimensions except the leftmost using constant expressions.

If for example SIZE is defined as a constant and the array has equal dimensions then you could write for example

```
void print_game(int game[][SIZE], int SIZE);
```

or

```
void run_game(int game[][SIZE], int SIZE);
```

and so on.